# Are there any pre defined methods to get the search results from google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am planning to develop an andriod app on top of google maps.I want search details in google maps and use the search results for further analysis.Are there any pre defined methods to get the search results from google maps?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To obtain data about locations you can use the Geocoder http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html